# Java docker kafka kraft simple connection

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Hi I'm using docker to host a local kafka kraft server. I'm trying to make a simple connection using java

My docker `docker-compose.yml` looks like this

```
version: "3.5"
services:

  kafka-gen:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.3
    hostname: kafka-gen
    container_name: kafka-gen
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/create_cluster_id.sh:/tmp/create_cluster_id.sh
      - ./clusterID:/tmp/clusterID
    command: "bash -c '/tmp/create_cluster_id.sh'"

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.3
    hostname: kafka1
    container_name: kafka1
    ports:
      - "39092:39092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: BROKER://kafka1:19092,EXTERNAL://kafka1:39092,CONTROLLER://kafka1:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: BROKER://kafka1:19092,EXTERNAL://kafka1:39092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: BROKER
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,BROKER:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'controller,broker'
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@kafka1:9093'
      KAFKA_METADATA_LOG_SEGMENT_MS: 15000
      KAFKA_METADATA_MAX_RETENTION_MS: 1200000
      KAFKA_METADATA_LOG_MAX_RECORD_BYTES_BETWEEN_SNAPSHOTS: 2800
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-combined-logs'
    volumes:
      - kafka1-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
      - ./scripts/update_run.sh:/tmp/update_run.sh
      - ./clusterID:/tmp/clusterID
    command: "bash -c '/tmp/update_run.sh && /etc/confluent/docker/run'"

volumes:
  kafka1-data:
```

and my java code(using `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.4.0`)

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:39092");
properties.setProperty("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty("value.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());

KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(
        "first_topic", "testm"
);
kafkaProducer.send(producerRecord);

kafkaProducer.flush();

kafkaProducer.close();
```

I'm getting

```
 WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error connecting to node kafka1:39092 (id: 1 rack: null)
java.net.UnknownHostException: kafka1
```

and the message is never pushed. Could you help me figure out either of my docker or the java connector have a problem?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way kafka works with advertised listeners.

Whenever a connection request comes into kafka, this is what happens inside:

1. It takes a look at where it receives the request
2. This incoming request is mapped to a connection:

   ```
   KAFKA_LISTENERS: BROKER://kafka1:19092,EXTERNAL://kafka1:39092,CONTROLLER://kafka1:9093
   ```
3. It then knows the name of your connection: In your case the "EXTERNAL" connection is used
4. It uses this name to return the ADVERTISED_LISTENER, **which then is used for the application to actually send/receive data**.

   ```
   KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: BROKER://kafka1:19092,EXTERNAL://kafka1:39092
   ```
5. In your case this is returned:

   ```
   EXTERNAL://kafka1:39092
   ```

You see exactly this also in your error message:

```
UnknownHostException: kafka1
```

And this makes totally sense: Your application is **outside** of the docker network, it doesnt know the host "kafka1", but this is what the kafka broker returns to actually send data to.

So to fix your issue you have to change the "ADVERTISED_LISTENER" variable to this:

```
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: BROKER://kafka1:19092,EXTERNAL://127.0.0.1:39092
```